# Admin authentication takes forever

Tags: login, authentication

I am running ubuntu 10.10 installed through wubi. When every I have to authenticate for administrative privileges (like for installing software), the authentication window just hangs there forever after I put in my password. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

once that happed to me so after i enter my password i wait like 3 seconds and i click on the "x" "exit" button and it works